# IN DART - toList() method is not converting an Iterable of int into list, but when it is applied inside print() it works fine. Why?

Tags: loops, dart, oop, variables, mapping

I have created a list 'numbers' then used 'map' method to loop over it and assigned the output to squares. Now I apply toList() method on 'squares' to convert it to a List type but in output it's printed as iterable of int. However when I do the same thing inside the print() method then it gives me the output as a list. So why is it not working outside the print() method?

```
void main() {
  const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  final squares = numbers.map((number) => number * number);
  squares.toList(); // I've applied toList() method here

  print(squares); // But I don't get a list from this output
  print(squares.toList()); // But I get it from this output. Why?
```

}

OUTPUT:

```
(1, 4, 9, 16)
[1, 4, 9, 16]
```

Comment: Check what `toList()` returns. Hint: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.3/dart-core/Iterable/toList.html ;)

Comment: You can never change the runtime type of an existing object.  You instead must create *new* objects with the desired type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`toList()` convert the data to list but you have to assign the result to a variable. Eg:

```
List list = squares.toList();
```

Then you can use the new variable.